# Cannot access child node value JSON

Tags: c#, json, object, nested, uri

I try to get some data nested in JSON, the `extendedData.e_ETP["value"]` that I get by making a request to an API to create a list with a key LUS_BU with the value of extendedData.e_ETP["value"].

But when I try to access the value I get the error : **Cannot access child value on Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.**

When I specify in the uri the id of an item where `extendedData.e_ETP is not null It works.

The thing is I want to put a default value for LUS_BU if its null or use the one from the extendedData.e_ETP if there is one

Here is a part of the c# code :

```
myUri = new Uri("https://ilucca.net/api/v3/users?dtContractStart=since,1900-01-01&dtContractEnd=until,2100-01-01,null&fields=id,firstName,lastName,employeeNumber,personalAccount,userAxisValues,legalEntityID,mail,dtContractEnd,dtContractStart,manager[name],birthDate,seniorityDate,gender,extendedData.e_ETP,extendedData.e_contracttype");
        request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myUri);
        request.Headers["Authorization"] = "ApiKey";
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            rep = JObject.Parse(s);

            salaries = rep["data"]["items"].Where(c => (string)c["name"] != "lad" && (int?)c["legalEntityID"] != 10).Select(c => new T_E_LuccaSalarie_LUS()
            {
                LUS_ETP = (c["extendedData"]["e_ETP"] != null ) ? (string)c["extendedData"]["e_ETP"]["value"] : "1"
            }).ToList();
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            string exMessage = ex.Message;
            if (ex.Response != null)
            {
                using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    exMessage = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(exMessage);
                }
            }
        }
```

JSON:

```
{
  "header": {
    "generated": "2021-01-22T16:12:53.4193558",
    "serverTime": 1395,
    "queryTime": 169,
    "queryCount": 18,
    "principal": "API Integration",
    "processId": 6956
  },
  "data": {
    "items": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "employeeNumber": "2",
        "personalAccount": "Z0",
        "userAxisValues_1": {
          "id": 10,
          "name": "FT04 SALES",
          "url": "https://ilucca.net/api/v3/axissections/48"
        },
        "legalEntityID": 1,
        "mail": "random@mail.com",
        "dtContractEnd": "2020-01-30T00:00:00",
        "dtContractStart": "2000-06-18T00:00:00",
        "manager": {
          "name": "John Doe"
        },
        "birthDate": "1959-08-23T00:00:00",
        "seniorityDate": "2010-06-18T00:00:00",
        "gender": "Female",
        "extendedData": {
          "e_ETP": null,
          "e_contracttype": {
            "id": 9556,
            "value": 16
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "metadata": null
}
```

Feel free to ask if you need any specific details or clarification on specific point.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. You have a property (`"data"`) outside of a containing object, and you have an object nested in an object without belonging to a property (see the first item in the `"items"` array).

Comment: As mentioned by @John, your Json is not valid. Check this screenshot where I've fixed your Json --- https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjgTB.png using https://app.quicktype.io/. Your posted Json has braces and comma issues.

Comment: I've edited the JSON part accordingly, I've made mistakes while trying to anonymize the information. Thanks

Comment: I don't see any issue when I tried replicating your scenario. Check this fiddle -- https://dotnetfiddle.net/MdRp6p which works for both `string` type casting and `ToObject<string>()` function.

Comment: First, thanks for checking, Ive edited the JSON again, its when the `extendedData.e_ETP` is null that I get the error.

Comment: how it's look like the `e_ETP` in the Json when she has a value?

Comment: @Sajid if its what your asking for, when it has a value, the e_ETP part of the json looks like this : `"e_ETP": { "id": 18418, "value": 1.0}`, the thing is that I get the error **Cannot access child value** when "e_ETP: null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comment if `e_ETP` is null then it comes as `"e_ETP": null` in your Json. That scenario represents that the token is type of `JValue` with value as null. In positive scenario, the `e_ETP` type is of `JObject`

Using below code you can validate the type and assign the value of `LUS_ETP`

```
LUS_ETP = jObj["data"]["items"][0]["extendedData"]["e_ETP"].GetType() == typeof(JObject) 
               ? jObj["data"]["items"][0]["extendedData"]["e_ETP"]["value"].Value<string>() 
               : "1";
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you very much for your patience and explanations.